# react jsx highcharts documentation advice needed

Tags: npm

I´m thinking about using React jsx highcharts for a project im working on, the only thing putting me off is I haven´t used highcharts before so I´d need some sort of documentation listing all of the different parameters available to play with, can´t seem to find this information anywhere, would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction, or give me some advice, maybe its worth just using react-highcharts instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the docs for Highcharts's API, and with any methods/properties that are normally in the configuration object for Highcarts, you would pass as props.

[Highcharts API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/)

Example:

```
chart: {
    type: 'column'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: [
  "foo",
  "bar",
],
type: 'category',
},
```

Would look something like this:

```
import { Chart, XAxis } from 'react-jsx-highcharts';
<Chart type={'category'}/>
 <XAxis categories={['foo', 'bar']} type={'category'}/>
```

There are only a few situations where the syntax would be different, but the highcharts-react-jsx documentation covers those edge cases in their documentation.